# Is there a known society without cult of love?

Tags: ancient-history

Was there ever a society in which sex was viewed either as a functional necessity, duty before the gods or pleasure without any admiration of love?

Comment: I would assume that orthodox religious societies e.g. in Christianity (such as the [Amish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amish) or [Hutterites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutterites)) and [Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_Judaism) may come close to viewing sex as duty before the gods, but then I may be wrongly prejudiced as an outsider.

Comment: @Drux: Nope, I think you're more or less right! I can speak from knowledge of the Catholic faith at least. In reality, many Catholic lay folk would not have viewed it in this narrow manner, for obvious/natural/human reasons, though it has been the official doctrine since the Early Church, I'd imagine.

Comment: @Drux - way way false for Judaism though. Romantic love is fully theologically approved of as foundation of family dynamic. Google "Song of Songs" :)

Comment: Also, "admiration of love" seems way way subjective to be answerable. VTC.

Answer (score -1):

The [Voluntary Human Extinction Movement](http://www.vhemt.org/) would answer your question in the affirmative, however, it is not a society per se, and it doesn't advocate against sex, but rather it advocates against procreation. I think that ultimately sex is viewed by nearly all human groups as being a necessary part of existence.

Comment: The [Church of the Flying Spaghetti Monster](http://www.venganza.org), on the other hand, welcomes all "into the loving embrace of His Noodly Appendage." :)

Comment: -1. First, it is not a society in the sense I was asking about. Second, this is plainly incorrect, according to their website it does not follow from their ideology that they have any special position about love.